# Joomla Backup to run Locally

Tags: joomla2.5

Can a downloaded backup of Joomla website be run on localhost? If yes, what changes I need to do locally?

I placed the unzipped backup folder under `C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla`. So now as I try to run loclhost `//localhost/joomla` it gives me following error.

`Database Error: Unable to connect to the Database: Could not connect to MySQL.`

Please note that I've not done any changes to backup. Just placed the unzipped backup downloaded via FTP in htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to download a copy of the website database and install this locally. If this is new to you, check out [Akeeba Backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606), it will simpplify your life when moving sites between different servers. It will bundle the database and site files into a nice, neat zipped package for you.

Comment: Thanks David, but I already removed everything from server. I've made changes to configuration.php for tmp and log paths, so it should route to localhost. Any help would be really really appreciated.

Comment: You mention what you have done with the unzipped backup files. I'm not clear what steps you have taken to dump, download and instal the database files. If you didn't manually try to copy the database from the server, check your backup files for an sql package.

Comment: Thanks, i've found the SQL package, where should this be placed in localhost?

Comment: ... sigh of relief. From configuration.php, note the name of the database, user and password. Open phpMyAdmin in xamp, create a new database and user with these same specs, then import this sql file into the database you just created. Let me know if you need a more detailed step by step.

Comment: @pksmile, I wanted to check that you have this working now and that all is good!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the database specifics are incorrect. Unless you have created the exact database name and user on localhost you'll need to edit configuration.php to straighten that out.